# Yii2 dataTables Filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yii2

I am using Yii2 and DataTables extension from Fedemotta (https://github.com/fedemotta/yii2-widget-datatables). And now I need to add column filters for my tables. So I am doing this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#datatables_cards-list').append('<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>');
$('#datatables_cards-list thead th').each( function () {    
    var title = $(this).text();
    $('#datatables_cards-list tfoot tr').append( '<th rowspan="1" colspan="1"><input type="text" placeholder="Шукати '+title+'" /></th> ' );
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#datatables_cards-list').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
} );
```

this is an example from dataTables website, but as far as my table does not have `<tfoot>` I am adding it throug js. The problem is, it's not finding anything. Whatever I am typing in search field, it says nothing was find. It works when I am putting search inputs right to my table header, but then if I click on input, column sorting changes, because I am clicking on it's header.

Here is PHP code

```
DataTables::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $cards,
                    'filterModel'=>$fModel,
                    'id'=>'cards-list',
                    'clientOptions'=>[
                        'language'=>Yii::$app->params['dataTablesLang'],
                    ],
                    'columns' => [
                         'balance',
                          .....
                    ]
               ]);
```

Comment: how have you configured the DataTable add the code

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam just edited my question

Comment: why are you trying to add filters via javascript whe you already are using the dataprovider with search model

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam because it is not displaying in my table. It works for GridView, but not for DataTables

Comment: Have you tried this too? https://github.com/NullRefExcep/yii2-datatables Here is a lot of examples.